# Use css overflow property in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to use css text-overflow ellipse property to label instead of concatenating ellipse to truncated label. Can i achieve truncation using overflow property in d3.js?

```
    svgObj
    .append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .append("tspan")
    .text(labelText);
```

Comment: `text-overflow` is not working on `<text>`, this property is not appplied on SVG related elements. Manualy concatenationg seems to be the only chooice.

Comment: thank you for clarifying